# Dependency resolution issues and best practices for updating an old angular nodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, mongoose

I'm returning to a project after several months of not working on it, and wondering if anyone has any good tips on what is the best way to go about updating and maintaining an out-of-date angular project. I'm quite lost and would like to know how an expert developer would deal with this.

In the past when I was working on it consistently I kept things up to date using the **NPM update or upgrade** commands, and I  fixed breaking changes as they occured from update to update. I tried to force those update commands this time around and I ended up breaking my code and having to re-start things back from an ealier iteration (thx github).

So now I am several versions behind on everything, and not quite sure how to proceed. I've been trying to look up some documentation for each specific version of the patches I need to update but I don't know where to start or what to prioritze. I understand I cant just update them each in one shot with a simple npm update command.

When I try to do an NPM install I get:

**npm ERR! code ERESOLVE**

**npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree**

- or if I try an NPM update:

**npm ERR! Found: mongoose@6.0.1**

**npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose**

**npm ERR!   mongoose@"^6.0.0" from the root project**

**npm ERR!**

**npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:**

**npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^5.2.1" from mongoose-unique-validator@2.0.3**

What is the first package I should worry about? What are important things to keep in mind here? I'm Not sure what to do and any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my packages after using the ncu package -u command (node-check-updates)]

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://update.angular.io/) guide?

Comment: What versions of `node` and `npm` are you using? What are the contents of your `package.json`?

Comment: @Trott Sorry, been avoiding this project, I've had some other computer related issues to work on before I could return to this one. - 

  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0",
    "npm": "6.8.0"

I have many packages over the years as I kind of used the app to learn about NPM and how packages like chalk for example worked.

Answer (score 1):

`npm update` will lead you only to the latest available dependencies,so you should've upgraded gradually your current Angular version right to your preferred one in order to keep your code journey perpetuate (you better use `Yarnpkg`)

Angular update gide : https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue. I solve it by downgrade mongoose version into "^5.2.1". Hope it is useful

Comment: This seemed to help, thank you. I edited the package json to reflect this mongoose version, and i ran an NPM i which failed, NPM told me to either force or enter npm i --legacy-peer-deps

I did the legacy peer deps and that seemed to work, my packages seem to be updated. Now I am working on getting this project linked to an old hosted heroku version so i can update it, so I tried to install the heroku CLI 

and I did a brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku

Which failed, and now i am updating the latest command line tools for xcode. Either way my app works locallly so thanks.